# I want to make Android app resposive layout for diffrent-diffrent screen size

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, responsive-design

**First Create *xml* file**

> ***By default*** : - activity_main

> **Small Phones** : - activity_main(sw360)

> **Large Phones** : - activity_main(sw480)

> **Extra large Phones/Tablets** : - activity_main(sw600)

**I want follow this condition but some error?????**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 320 && config.smallestScreenWidthDp <= 480) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main(sw320));
    } else if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 481 && config.smallestScreenWidthDp <= 600) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main(sw480));
    } else(config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 601{
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main(sw600));
    } 
  }
```

[See this image to clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhYVL.png)

Comment: You don't need to set different layouts in the Activity. If your layout files are created with same names and in correct configuration folder , android OS will automatically pick the layout file according to device screen size.

Comment: but I want the backend code to follow

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to program it, when you use the correct folder and naming structure the system will determine the correct layout or use the default (which is in the `layout` folder).

See this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes#alternative-layouts) which tells more about the folder structure.
Eg:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml                # For handsets
res/layout-land/main_activity.xml           # For handsets in landscape
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml        # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw600dp-land/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets in landscape
```

So in your case it would be:

```
res/layout/activity_main.xml                # default (smaller than 360dp available width)
res/layout-sw360dp/activity_main.xml        # Small phones (360dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw480dp/activity_main.xml        # Large phones (480dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw600dp/activity_main.xml        # XLarge phones (600dp wide and bigger)
```

Your Activity can then use this OnCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: can you tell me a little more detail...

Comment: The default folder for the layouts is the /res/layout/ folder, when nothing else is specified it will pick the layout from that folder. You can add other layout folders with qualifiers, these. The system will look if the device or current state of the app is valid to that qualifier, if so it can use that layout, otherwise it will fallback the the default. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes#alternative-layouts)

Comment: When your layout does not have to be adaptive but only responsive you can also use a [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes#flexible-layout), it's flexible and scales well

Answer (score 0):

use wrap content and match-parent instead of giving hard dimension to views.